# How to achieve migration of huge DBs using Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, azure-sql-database

I am using EF 6.1.1 on SQL Azure DB which has **four million records** and migration has to change the data type of a column from `int` to `varchar`.

I tried 2 methods:

**1. EF auto migration**

Timeout window set to max value, `CommandTimeout = Int32.MaxValue;` 
Migration was successful in 40 minutes.

**2. Using SQL script**

Same migration I tried with my own script, where I create a temp table column with the type `varchar` and convert the data, copy it to temp table, then copy converted column to new column in original table. This method I tried in chunks of operations starting from 10k, 20k, 50k records, still migration time was almost same: around 40 minutes.

Is it expected to take such a long time for a migration on huge DB?

Only option left for me is coded migration in EF.

Comment: You don't use EF for stuff like that. You just run a script on your DB. Create column, update records, delete old column, do any reindexing if necessary.